# [<UICollectionViewCell 0x14fd06a80> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I've been getting the error message "[<UICollectionViewCell 0x14fd06a80> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key" for an image attached to a custom cell in a UICollectionView.
The cell's IBoutlets are correctly linked up in the interface editor. There are no warning icons next to them.
I'm not quite sure whats going on.

Here's the code for the custom cell:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN


@interface CollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *maskName3;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *maskImage;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Here's what I've got in the interface builder:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems that the cell is of class `UICollectionViewCell` and not of the subclass `CollectionViewCell`

Comment: It is, I've included another image

Comment: It isn't. The crash message tells you that.

Comment: then why does it show up as collectionviewcell in the navigator in the 2nd picture? And why do the outlets connect to it?

Comment: Because the cell you are dequeuing isn't what you think it is.

Comment: cell dequeuing works fine. the cell functions fine without the label and image with programatically generated labels, but it has an issue when I add the labels and image to the NIB

Comment: The exception message says that you are associating your nib file with an instance of `UICollectionViewCell`not `CollectionViewCell`.  You have probably messed up your "files owner" or something.

Comment: I've checked that. That doesnt seem to be the issue either. Here's my code for the dequeing:- (nonnull __kindof Celler1 *)collectionView:(nonnull UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //NSLog(@"Got this far");
    Celler1 *cell3 = [_maskGrid dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Celler1" forIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: I've changed my custom cell class to be called Celler1, I've associated it with the cell I'm using. I've reconstructed the entire view controller and all its subviews and I'm still getting the same issue

Comment: Ok, finally worked out what was wrong. For some reason, telling the cell that it inherited its module from its target was causing it to crash. I unticked that and now it works fine. Weird.

Comment: You were probably getting a warning in the runtime console that `CollectionViewCell` wasn't found.  In that case `UICollectionViewCell` is used.

Comment: maybe, its all working now at least.